# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at handleChange

Tags: javascript, typescript

In JavaScript, it works normally, but when trying to use TypeScript with this handleChange function, this error is generated every time I type something in the entries. TypeError not captured: Object (...) is not a function in handleChange.

How do I group my entries into a useState array of objects?

in the functional function I am inserting through each setValues ​​each object typed, I would like to continue doing so.

my values ​​should look like this:
values ​​{
first name',
lastName: 'LastName',
email: 'email',
phone: '(xx) xxxx-xxxx',
local_user: 'External'
}

```
const [values, setValues] = useState ([]);

function handleChange (e) {

  setValues ​​({... values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value, local_user:'External'})
}
```

Note: This works in javascript without any problems.

Comment: 1. Please translate your post to English. Google translate will be sufficent. 2. If your state is an Array, you need to pass an Array to setValues (or change the initial state to empty object). To keep your code consistent with JS version, you probably need the latter.

Comment: would you have an example of how I pass this array to setValues? because i'm adding one by one when typed

Comment: You either use `values.concat(NEW_OBJECT)` or `[...values, NEW_OBJECT]`. See https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove

Comment: What I noticed in the tests is that when I put the brackets like this [e.target.name] it generates the error. Ex.:setValues ​​({... values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}), If I put the brackets on it doesn't find the variable.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't change JavaScript behavior. You are mistaken

Comment: This is strange, but it just doesn't work, if I use the way it appears, the message that setValeu is not a function, I don't know what may be happening anymore.

Comment: I need to capture the input name and the value, to generate an array of objects, as in this example: {name: value}
{base: 'Name User Base',
new: 'Name User New',
email:'email@email.com '}. Would you have any other way to refer me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon, thanks for the tips, but I managed to solve the problem, certainly the function had no problem as indicated in the comments, what I did, was to restart the server development with crtl + c (windows) and run again with yarn dev. And so it worked again, you will understand.